# what is the typescript type of app in vue 3

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuejs3, vue-auth

I am using Vue 3 and [`vue-auth`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@websanova/vue-auth) together.

For `vue-auth`, my project needs to create **http/index.ts**, containing:

```
import axios from 'axios';

axios.defaults.baseURL = process.env.VUE_APP_API_URL;

export default (app) => {
    app.axios = axios;
    app.$http = axios;

    app.config.globalProperties.axios = axios;
    app.config.globalProperties.$http = axios;
}
```

but here I have a type error for `app`:

[image]

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 3):

`app` here would be an [application instance](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/application.html#the-application-instance), which the `vue` package exports as `App`. And if you want to attach `axios` and `$http` to the application instance, you'd have to use an `any`-type assertion.

```js
               
import type { App } from 'vue';
import axios from 'axios';

axios.defaults.baseURL = process.env.VUE_APP_API_URL;
                      
export default (app: App) => {
    (app as any).axios = axios;
    (app as any).$http = axios;

    app.config.globalProperties.axios = axios;
    app.config.globalProperties.$http = axios;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not exactly an error, but rather a warning that if you don't define a type, the parameter will have the type: `any`. In that case, the IDE just advises you to use `any`, or whatever type you want

```typescript
export default (app: any) => {
    app.axios = axios;
    app.$http = axios;

    app.config.globalProperties.axios = axios;
    app.config.globalProperties.$http = axios;
}
```

Is possible to disable this warning adding `"noImplicitAny": false` at your `tsconfig.json` if you want (:

Comment: While this answer is correct, it is often not advised to do so. Package `vue` exports types for its components, as seen in the answer provided by @tony19. It would be a better practice to type it eplicitly, than disable warnings or use `any`.